# Matching whole words using "in" in python

Tags: python

I've been searching around for some time for this, but have still not found an answer, maybe its got some thing to do with regular expressions, but i think there should be a simple answer that I am missing here. It seems very trivial to me ... here goes:

On the python interpreter I get:

```
"abc" in "abc123"
```

as True.

I want it a command that returns a False. I want the entire word to be matched.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want "abc 123" to match as well?

Comment: Include some cases of what you need.Your question is a little unclear to me.

Comment: Yup .. got my answer ... thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to do a plain match of just one word, use ==:

```
'abc' == 'abc123' # false
```

If you're doing `'abc' in ['cde','fdabc','abc123']`, that returns False anyway:

```
'abc' in ['cde','fdabc','abc123'] # False
```

The reason `'abc' in 'abc123'` returns true, from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in):

> For the Unicode and string types, `x in y` is true if and only if **`x` is a
>   substring** of `y`. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`.

So for comparing against a single string, use '==', and if comparing in a collection of strings, `in` can be used (you could also do `'abc' in ['abc123']` - since the behaviour of `in` works as your intuition imagines when `y` is a *list* or collection of sorts.

Comment: By the way, how do you look up the python docs for `in`?! googling "python" "in" isn't all that helpful... (I am curious as to why `'abc' in 'abc123'` returns true).

Comment: you can do `help("in")` in your interpreter.

Answer (score 12):

`in` isn't how it's done.

```
>>> re.search(r'\babc\b', 'abc123')
>>> re.search(r'\babc\b', 'abc 123')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1146780>
```

Comment: I think this must be the best

Answer (score 6):

I might not understand your question, but it seems like what you want is `"abc123" == "abc"`. This returns `False`, whereas `"abc123" == "abc123"` returns `True`.

Perhaps what you are looking for is matching on whole words but splitting on whitespace? That is, `"abc"` does not match `"abc123"`, but it does match `"abc def"`? If that is the case, you want something like this:

```
def word_in (word, phrase):
    return word in phrase.split()

word_in("abc", "abc123") # False
word_in("abc", "abc def") # True
```

Comment: The for loop is redundant, you can use `if w in phrase.split()`, or even simply `return w in phrase.split()`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used a small trick. The whole word should be surrounded with spaces. So, if I want to find word like "**Kill**", I will search for " **Kill** ". In this case, it wont match with word like "**Skill**"

```
' kill ' in myString
```

Comment: Nice trick but this has some obvious downsides. E.g. when searching a text with punctuation: `kill?` and `kill,` won't be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a wrong shot but it can be done in a more simple way.

```py
def word_in(needle,haystack,case_sensitive=True):
    if needle + ' ' in haystack or ' ' + needle + ' ' in haystack or needle + ' ' in haystack:
        return True

    return False

print word_in('abc','abc123')    
print word_in('abc','abc 123')
```

First example produces False, the other True

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use **find** method and compare the result to -1:

```
>>> a = "abc123"
>>> a.find("abc")
0
>>> a.find("bcd")
-1
```